# Parsing varchar as int for inserting values into the database

Tags: c#, database, parsing

I have to add 4 values into my table:@SNTeacher,@name,@pwd and @courseID.The @courseID is a FK in my RegisterTeacher table and a PK I Courses table along with another attribute-@coursename.
My problem is that when I want to insert the values into the table, I get an error at @courseID saying that it can't convert from varchar to int although my @courseID is an int.

My @courseID and @coursename are binded to comboBoxcourse1 and it has DisplayMember-coursename and ValueMember=courseID.My opinion is that it makes the confusion between the two of them since @coursename is a varchar, but then again I don't see the logic since I'm adding the @courseID parameter to the table RegisterTeacher.

I also tried to parse it in 3 different ways that I have also found here, on Stack Overflow but still I get errors saying that the input string was not in a correct format.

This is my code with the error and in is also the last method I used to try to parse the value:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\VIAUniversityCollegeAttendanceApp\VIAUniversityCollegeAttendanceApp\DatabaseAttendanceStudents.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into RegisterTeacher values(@SNTeacher,@name,@pwd,@courseID) ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SNTeacher", textBoxSN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",textBoxName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", textBoxpwd.Text);
    string nvarchar = "@courseID";
    var one = int.Parse(nvarchar);
    var bone = int.TryParse(nvarchar, out one);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseID", comboBoxcourse1.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Registration succesfull!");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting  comboBoxcourse1.Text to int?

Comment: Yes,I have also tried that and I get "The input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: From AddWithValue("@courseID", comboBoxcourse1.Text) To : AddWithValue("@courseID", int.Parse(comboBoxcourse1.Text))

Comment: Yes,that has been also on my trial list :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
int parameterValue;

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@courseID", SqlDbType.Int);

if(Int32.TryParse(comboBoxcourse1.SelectedValue?.ToString() ?? String.Empty, out parameterValue))
{
  parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}
else
{
  parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
}

cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: `comboBoxcourse1.Text` is wrong, since, per the question, it is bound to `courseName`. You need the value, not the text

Comment: well i took that from the code part of the question: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseID", comboBoxcourse1.Text);

Comment: Well, if there's a question about something not working, it's likely not helpful to copy that code...

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'courseID', table 'C:\USERS\USER\SOURCE\REPOS\VIAUNIVERSITYCOLLEGEATTENDANCEAPP\VIAUNIVERSITYCOLLEGEATTENDANCEAPP\DATABASEATTENDANCESTUDENTS.MDF.dbo.RegisterTeacher'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: Sorry,I wanted to write along with the exception that I thank you for the solution,but it doesn't work since that is the exception that I get :)

Comment: corrected my answer. do all your combobox items have a numeric value?

Comment: Yes,they do and it's not null for each one of them

Comment: Thank you for the last solution Marco Forberg,It works! :D .Saved my day,get a correct answer!